# How to bind multiple keys in gnu screen, specifically using arrow keys

Tags: linux, terminal, ncurses, gnu-screen, terminfo

First off, I'm using Opensuse 13.2 64-bit  and also Arch_Linux 64-bit
Can't get the bind to work for either of them (well, the binds that I want), but I'm mostly focused on the Arch_Linux.  Also, using openbox wm, xfce4-terminal.  ( in opensuse using konsole and gnome 3) and my $TERM is set to xterm-256color in my ~/.bashrc and is switched to screen-256color when using screen in opensuse, but strangely is not changed in Arch.

I want to bind C-a down: to focus down, C-a up: to focus up, C-a left: to focus left etc..  Lets just focus on focus down for the moment.
I've tried everything in my ~/.screenrc file

```
bind "\E[B" focus down
bind "\EOB" focus down
bind "^[[B" focus down
bind "^[OB" focus down
bind "\033[B" focus down
bind "\033OB" focus down
bind "\033\133\102" focus down

bind j focus down # works fine
```

Nothing catches the down arrow key.  I CAN use the following

```
bind -k kd focus down
```

however, I also want to bind multiple keys using the arrows and AFAIK the -k option only allows binding 1 key (or shift + left/right) .  Actually I'm lucky I can even use the -k option since it is not documented.

Now I've checked my kd (termcap) and kcud1 (terminfo) using infocmp

```
infocmp -1 | grep kcud1
    kcud1=\EOB,
infocmp -1C | grep kd
    :kd=\EOB:\
```

and BTW these symbols can be looked up [here for termcap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/termcap.5.html) and [here for terminfo and its termcap equivelancies](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html)  (actually I guess you can just use: man terminfo)

when I use Ctrl-v and press down arrow I get

```
 ^[[B

 showkey -a
 ^[[B    27 0033 0x1b
         91 0133 0x5b
         66 0102 0x42
```

Anyone know how to go about this.  I want to know why I can't use bind without the -k termcap_name and/or how to use combo of keys(such as ctrl/alt) and termcap names.  Thanks for all and any info.

I've tried setting termcapinfo also with no luck.  don't think I'm using it right.

```
termcapinfo * kd=\EOB
bind "\EOB" focus down

termcapinfo * kd=\E[B
bind "\E[B" focus down
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that GNU screen doesn't permit binding sequences of multiple keys.

Quoting the man page:

> bind [-c class] key [command [args]]
>
> Bind  a command to a key.
>   ...
>   The key argument is either a single
>   character, a two-character sequence of the form "^x" (meaning
>   "C-x"), a backslash followed by an octal number (specifying
>   the ASCII code of the character), or  a backslash followed by a
>   second character, such as "\^" or "\".  The argument can also
>   be quoted, if you like.
>   ...

Comment: I think you missed something..."two-character sequence of the form "^x"(meaning "C-x").  But my question is centered around getting bind to bind to cursor key down, which IS one key.   My next step will be to get it to bind to C-Down.  Thanks

Comment: Cursor key down is one *key*, but it sends multiple characters (more than two).  So you cannot do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

As said [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754513/binding-arrow-keys-in-gnu-screen), try:

`bindkey "^A^[OB" focus down`

The `vim` trick is really helpful to get the code for the combinations you want (for example, if you wanted the combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>*down*</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>*down*</kbd>, this would be `^[[1;5B` instead of `^[OB`).

Credit should go to [koyae](https://askubuntu.com/users/746501/koyae) for the original answer.